# Split based on specific column value and then split into X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, train-test-split

Instead of using the function `train_test_split`, I am splitting based on a specific column value. In my case, week number 52 in the dataframe will become the test set. How shall I split into X_train, y_train to fit into the model after splitting based on the column value?

Any input is appreciated.

```
def regressionsquare(data, yvar, xvars): 
    lm = LinearRegression()
    X = data[xvars].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = data[yvar].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    for holdouts in itertools.combinations(data['week_number'].unique(), 52):
        train = data[~data['week_number'].isin(holdouts)]
        test = data[data['week_number'].isin(holdouts)]

    *****  How do I split train into X_train, y_train here ****
    ***** How do I split test into X_test, y_test here ****

    lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predicted = lm.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input dataset, and expected dataset.

Comment: Do it the similar way as you've done with `X` and `y`, but after splitting by the week. Like `X_train = train[xvars].values.reshape(-1, 1)`, `y_train = train[yvar].values.reshape(-1, 1)` and same for the test data.